# Fetching correct row depending on column value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need help figuring out how to fetch the correct row, depending on the rows column value but by only making one query. I want an array to store all rows, but then fetch the right value from the array.

This is how my table is structured:

```
ID  Name    Text    Page
```

Using an PHP Array, I want to echo `text` depending on what the value of `name` on that key is.
This is my PHP code to fetch the table:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USR,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
    $db->set_charset("utf8mb4");

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM content WHERE Page='index';");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

I tried this, but for obvious reasons it didn't really work:

```
<h1><?php if($row['Name'] == 'slide_1_title') echo $row['Text']; ?></h1>
```

I would gladly appreciate someone helping me out on this one. How can I solve this?

Comment: show result of `$row`

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT text FROM content WHERE name='slide_1_title'`?

Comment: It sounds like you need to get all rows where `Page='index'` and add these to a data structure where it is easy to get the `Text` based on the `Name`.

Comment: @jeroen that is basically what I want, yes! I want to avoid making too many SQL queries. I only want to make one and then use PHP to search the result-array and fetch a value

Comment: Then get all rows, loop over them and add the entries to an associative array where the `Name` is the key and the `Text` is the value. Then you can simply use `$array['slide_1_title']`, etc. where you need it.

Comment: @jeroen Thanks! That did it.

Comment: I wonder why nobody suggested a simple query 

    `SELECT * FROM content WHERE Page='index' AND Name = 'slide_1_title'`

which is what the OP needs

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not really, I wanted all data in an array so I would only have to make a query once

Comment: it is impossible to tell from your question, so the answer stands

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it thanks to @jeroen!

I simply made an assoc array and inserted the values I wanted in a loop like so:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM content WHERE page='index';");
$content = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $content[$row['name']] = $row['text'];
}

echo $content['slide_1_title'];
```

Answer (score -2):

**Please Check this :**

1) if there's something wrong with this: "SELECT * FROM content WHERE page='index';"

check if  `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` is returning rows

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result)
if($count>0){
   echo "query ran and returned row(s)";
}else echo "query Didn't ran";
```

If the query is returning rows then:

2) this `if($row['name'] == 'slide_1_title')` might be failing